# How do I get back to the Dunes after entering the Steamworks on the Genocide Route?

Tags: undertale-yellow

I am doing a [Genocide Route](https://undertaleyellow.wiki.gg/wiki/Genocide_Route) run of Undertale Yellow. After finishing the [Dunes](https://undertaleyellow.wiki.gg/wiki/Dunes) and entering the [Steamworks](https://undertaleyellow.wiki.gg/wiki/Steamworks), I realized I had accidentally missed an item that would help with the final boss.

> The [Golden Cactus](https://undertaleyellow.wiki.gg/wiki/Golden_Cactus), which is part of a 3 item set needed to get the [Golden Bandana](https://undertaleyellow.wiki.gg/wiki/Golden_Bandana), the best defensive item in the game.

I tried backtracking to the Dunes, but I can't go back through the vault door I used to enter. In a Pacifist or Neutral run I could fast travel back with the Underground Postal Service, but this is unavailable on the Genocide Route.

Is it possible to return to the Dunes after entering the Steamworks Lab on the Genocide Route?